Google Tink - Handling the scenario of key compromise
I understand that Google Tink provides support for working with multiple keys with single  primary key along with key rotation support.
But my questions is, lets say I have 1 million entries encrypted using key-1 (primary now) and persisted in my backed data store. Now I realise that the primary key in the keyset is compromised and I generate and add a new key to the keyset and promote it to the new primary. This is good for new encryptions and decryptions of new and old data.
But my concern is about those 1 million entries in my data store which are living with a compromised key. How can I secure those?
